# JQ and adding keys with other key values and string interpolation

Tags: bash, jq

I am  using JQ with bash and looking to add a URL for a vulnerability output and I am building the string based on one of the JSON object keys. Been pretty stumped figuring out how to get this to work.

Sample of the data looks like this:

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "os": "Debian GNU 11",
  "vulnerabilities": [
    {
      "CVEID": "CVE-2023-29491",
      "Product": "ncurses-base",
      "Severity": "HIGH",
      "Version": "6.2+20201114-2+deb11u1",
      "Description": "ncurses before 6.4 20230408, when used by a setuid application, allows local users to trigger security-relevant memory corruption via malformed data in a terminfo database file that is found in $HOME/.terminfo or reached via the TERMINFO or TERM environment variable.\n"
    },
    {
      "CVEID": "CVE-2022-29458",
      "Product": "ncurses-base",
      "Severity": "HIGH",
      "Version": "6.2+20201114-2+deb11u1",
      "Description": "ncurses 6.3 before patch 20220416 has an out-of-bounds read and segmentation violation in convert_strings in tinfo/read_entry.c in the terminfo library.\n"
    }
  ]
}
```

Basically what I am looking to do is have the data come out looking like this with a MITRE and NIST URL built based on the "CVEID" value:

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "os": "Debian GNU 11",
  "vulnerabilities": [
    {
      "CVEID": "CVE-2023-29491",
      "Product": "ncurses-base",
      "Severity": "HIGH",
      "Version": "6.2+20201114-2+deb11u1",
      "Description": "ncurses before 6.4 20230408, when used by a setuid application, allows local users to trigger security-relevant memory corruption via malformed data in a terminfo database file that is found in $HOME/.terminfo or reached via the TERMINFO or TERM environment variable.\n"
      "MITRE_URL": "https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2023-29491",
      "NIST_URL": "https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-29491"
    },
    {
      "CVEID": "CVE-2022-29458",
      "Product": "ncurses-base",
      "Severity": "HIGH",
      "Version": "6.2+20201114-2+deb11u1",
      "Description": "ncurses 6.3 before patch 20220416 has an out-of-bounds read and segmentation violation in convert_strings in tinfo/read_entry.c in the terminfo library.\n"
      "MITRE_URL": "https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2022-29458",
      "NIST_URL": "https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-29458" 
   }
  ]
}
```

Doing something like this does work, but it extracts the objects from .vulnerabilities[] so I cannot pipe them to TSV for my final output:

```
jq -r \
  --arg MITRE_URL "https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=" \
  --arg NIST_URL "https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/" \
  '.vulnerabilities[] | select(.CVEID) += {MITRE_URL: "\($MITRE_URL)\(.CVEID)", NIST_URL: "\($NIST_URL)\(.CVEID)"}' <<<"$ASSESSMENT_RESULTS"
```

Output of above ^ :

```
{
  "CVEID": "CVE-2023-29491",
  "Product": "ncurses-base",
  "Severity": "HIGH",
  "Version": "6.2+20201114-2+deb11u1",
  "Description": "ncurses before 6.4 20230408, when used by a setuid application, allows local users to trigger security-relevant memory corruption via malformed data in a terminfo database file that is found in $HOME/.terminfo or reached via the TERMINFO or TERM environment variable.\n",
  "MITRE_URL": "https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2023-29491",
  "NIST_URL": "https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-29491"
}
{
  "CVEID": "CVE-2022-29458",
  "Product": "ncurses-base",
  "Severity": "HIGH",
  "Version": "6.2+20201114-2+deb11u1",
  "Description": "ncurses 6.3 before patch 20220416 has an out-of-bounds read and segmentation violation in convert_strings in tinfo/read_entry.c in the terminfo library.\n",
  "MITRE_URL": "https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2022-29458",
  "NIST_URL": "https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-29458"
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm confused by this: You say the problem with your existing solution is that you can't generate TSV, but you aren't showing how you're trying to generate TSV that can't be adapted to be combined with that solution. You're adequately describing your inputs, and adequately describing your current output, but please be more explicit about exactly what _doesn't_ work.

Comment: BTW, are you familiar with `|=`? If you want to leave things you're changing attached to your parents, changing from `|` to `|=` may be the only change you need; I'd add that as an answer, but the question is unclear enough about what's going on that I have to consider it guesswork.

Comment: Hi Charles, thank you for the reply. Actually I didn't know that |= was for leaving children objects attached to parents. That is pretty much what I am looking for. 

What is happening when I try to create a TSV from this output, it will create a TSV row for each object because it is not seeing the output as an array.

Any idea how I would format this example to use |=, this doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: `'.vulnerabilities[] |= select(.CVEID) += {MITRE_URL: "\($MITRE_URL)\(.CVEID)", NIST_URL: "\($NIST_URL)\(.CVEID)"}' `

Comment: `.vulnerabilities |= map(if .CVEID? != null then . + {MITRE_URL: "\($MITRE_URL)\(.CVEID)", NIST_URL: "\($NIST_URL)\(.CVEID)"} else . end)`

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much. Sorry if I didn't explain this one well. If you'd like to post that I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|=` can be used to replace an element with a new value without deleting prior parts of the tree. Thus, consider:

```
.vulnerabilities |= map(
  if .CVEID? != null then
    . + {MITRE_URL: "\($MITRE_URL)\(.CVEID)",
         NIST_URL:  "\($NIST_URL)\(.CVEID)"}
  else . end
)
```